# Why the child process can't finish, even if the code has go out of the function run?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the codes like this:
It is clear the 'finished' has been printed out. but join still blocks.
Why should this happend?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
class MyProcess(Process):
    def run(self):
        ## do someting 
        print 'finished'       

processes = []
for i in range(3):
    p = MyProcess()
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Comment: I'm curious, is that all of your code? I tried it under Python 2 and 3 and both of them seemed to work when I fixed the syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

you should add this line `if __name__ == '__main__':` for things to work properly

Explanation:
your main script will be imported by `process.py` module, then it will execute your script lines 2 times, one during importing and one from your script execution,

here is the runtime error if we didn't include `if __name__ == '__main__':`

```
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

your working code in python 3.6 is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
class MyProcess(Process):
    def run(self):
        ## do someting 
        print ('finished')       

processes = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(3):
        p = MyProcess()
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print('we are done here .......')
```

output:

```
finished
finished
finished
we are done here .......
```

Answer (score 0):

`join` would not block if the task is finished, also your program is invalid.

```
for i in 3: # X integer is not iterable,
for i in range(3): # should be like this.
```